Why is my array misaligned in the console, despite the fact that I have centered it?
I programmed a simple Convay's Game of Life as a C# console application for my own enjoyment. One of the things I want to achieve, for aesthetic reasons, is that the array which I am using to actually host the game is centered in the console. That is, when the windowed console opens, the array is square in the middle of it. However when I run the program what I get is this:

While I am not the sharpest tool in the shed, I would say that "centered" is not the way to describe the aforementioned.
Here are the values that I have calculated, as well as my Display function which coordinates this whole effort, to try to achieve my goal:
int gameWindowWidth = 16;
int gameWindowHeight = 16;
int displayPosWidth = (Console.WindowWidth - gameWindowWidth) / 2;
int displayPosHeight = (Console.WindowHeight - gameWindowHeight) / 2;
string displayPosWidthFill = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, " ", displayPosWidth).ToString();
string displayPosHeightFill = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, " ", displayPosHeight).ToString();

static void DisplayGame(char[,] gameWindow, int refreshRate, string displayPosWidthFill, string displayPosHeightFill) {
    foreach (char a in displayPosHeightFill) {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < gameWindow.GetLength(0); x++) {
        Console.Write(displayPosWidthFill);
        for (int y = 0; y < gameWindow.GetLength(1); y++) {
            Console.Write(gameWindow[x, y].ToString() + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(refreshRate);
    Console.Clear();
}

From what I read in the documentation, Console.WindowWidth calculates by columns (I assume this translates well to characters i.e. like a grid of characters) and Console.WindowHeight does the same but using rows. So, while I may be an idiot, I cannot see why this would not work. Am I missing the obvious or is there a more fundamental reason that stems from Console behaviour? I require your assistance.

Your for loops are the wrong way round. You need the outer loop to iterate over the height (i.e. the rows) and the inner loop over the width (the columns).
Change your for block to this:
for (int y = 0; y < gameWindow.GetLength(1); y++)
{
    Console.Write(displayPosWidthFill);
    for (int x = 0; x < gameWindow.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        Console.Write(gameWindow[x, y].ToString() + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}

and it should work as desired.

I tried this. However, I still encounter the same problem, the array is not centered in the horizontal plane. Do you have further ideas? If you are willing to look, I could share my GitHub repository with the full code or I could update the question with it, though I am not sure whether StackOverflow likes posting a 100+ source code on a question.

Hi - posting your full code is fine provided it's not egregiously long. 100 lines or so should be ok. If it's possible to reduce it to a [MRE], that would be ideal. Also, I would be interested to know what changed after you made this code change; was there any difference in the output?

I am afraid I have unlucky news for you, as I just found a solution to my problem, though guided by your first answer. However, not all is lost for you for I still require your help. Firstly, your proposed change did not have an effect on how the code was displayed, it remained the same. Secondly, the way I fixed the issue was by multiplying the gameWindowWidth by two as I forgot to account for the whitespaces. Where my problem then lies is that doing the same for the height gives an IndexOutOfBounds error as the Console height is only 30. But still, why is it that the two are not the same?

It seems I truly am an idiot as I just grasped why the problem does not exist in the vertical plane. No whitespaces exist between cells in the vertical plane given I did not program such behaviour into my code. Thus, there would be no need to account for such behaviour when calculating the proper offsets to have a centered array. I am apologize for wasting your time.

Also, @Neil, thank you for helping. Your suggestion nudged me just right to come to the answer myself.

Multiplying the gameWindowWidth by two in the displayPosWidthFill took into account the additional offsets generated by the whitespaces when displaying them in the console. Thus, the problem of a non-centered array was solved.
